# How do you use a BIGINT as an Auto-Incrementing Primary Key in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to mimic [wordpress' primary key size](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png) which is BIGINT(20) but it seems that laravel doesn't have a native function to do this.. I saw a [page in the laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=47231) and got a code like this:

`$table->bigInteger('id')->primary();`

but when i try to attach a foreign key to that id during `artisan migrate`, there is a MYSQL error that is thrown:

> > [Exception]
> >     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db.#sql-
> >     1730_15' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint users_role_id_foreign foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`)) (Bindings: array (
> >     ))

What is the proper way to do this or where do i get this thing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: This is not laravel issue, it's related to foreignkey, the column pair of foreignkey and it's primarykey must be of same type, you can remove primarykey, change type of both columns and set primarykey back

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You most likely forgot to also set the type of your `role_id` foreign key as `BIGINT(20)` as well. This isn't really a Laravel issue, but rather MySQL's.

---

By the way, Laravel does have a native function to do this:

```
$this->bigIncrements('id');
```

This takes care of making it **unsigned**, **auto increment** and **primary key**.

Comment: Hi, seems `->primary()` doesn't make it an auto-increment key.. maybe that's why. now my question is how should i have done it with laravel?

Comment: Found the native function for this. Updated the answer.

Comment: yeah saw it already too ([see here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11214)). was about to answer my own question but you edited it before me.. **the problem is the error persists** even if i use `$this->bigIncrements('id');` on both users and roles tables..

Comment: and yes it is now a native function, just not yet documented on the main site.. it is on the [API](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Schema.Blueprint.html) but not on the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) yet

Comment: Ye, most of the methods arent't there, mainly because there's a lot that's inherited form other projects, suc. Anyway. can I see the rest of your mgiration?

Comment: oh, nvm.. found it while i was copy pasting my code to the question.. yes it is indeed a type mismatch. didn't realize i was still using `$table->unsignedInteger('role_id');`, i have updated it to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');` now. thanks a lot!

Comment: @reikyoushin I have also done the same mistake, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

When using bigInteger() also applying it to [foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys) in some table, make sure you connect it properly with unsignedBigInteger(),

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('create_this_table_after_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
           // Other Columns
        });
        Schema::table('create_this_table_after_users', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            // Other Constraints 
        });
}
```

[Reference Link of the Laravel 4.2 Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns)

Comment: Thanks, mate! I was searching why I keep getting this error `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`.

Comment: :) Glade i helped you.. Happy Coding

Comment: Oh man after so many tries with my migration in Laravel 5.8. This helped a lot.