# Laravel Migration : Errcode: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to execute this migration :

Users :

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar_url');
            $table->string('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Articles :

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->enum('state', ['draft', 'published']);
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

But when I migrate I get the following error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `blog_api`.`#sql-2b70_7b` (Errcode: 150 "Foreign key constraint is inc
>     orrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `articles` add constraint `articles_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users`
>
>    (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

I already tried to rename big integer and big increments to simple integer and increments withouth success.

Comment: How are you defining your `users.id` ?

Comment: You have shared `comments` table please share `users` table and make sure the `FK` and the `id` datatype matches!

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902308/5928015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be one unassignedBigInteger and then you set your foreign key.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints Please check the official documentation

Besides,

Please be carefull with order of migration. It starts from the first file through to latest one, so if you are trying to set foreign key for the table hasn't been created yet, it will throw an error.

E.g

Users table has foreign key relation with articles and like following;

- create_users_table
- create_articles_table

Since articles table not created yet, you will not be able to assign. For such cases like this, i suggest you to use "add_foreign_keys_to_articles" after all basic structure of tables created.

```
     Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
   $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            });
```